# How can i emit a string in service and get in component

Tags: angular, angular2-services, angular2-directives

I want to emit a string when the util.service.ts handled some errors, so that i can get this message in app.component.ts and show it, but i can not subscribe the emitter.
  this is my code, but it do not work:

in util.service.ts:

```
export class UtilService {
  errMsgEmitter = new EventEmitter();
  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    let errMsg: string;
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body['error'] || JSON.stringify(body);
      errMsg = `${error['status']} - ${error['statusText'] || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      errMsg = error['message'] ? error['message'] : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(errMsg);
    this.errMsgEmitter.emit(errMsg);
    return Observable.throw(errMsg);
   }
  /**
   * get event emitter
   * @returns {EventEmitter<any>}
   */
  getNavChangeEmitter() {
    return this.errMsgEmitter;
  }
```

in app.component.ts i have this:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.utilService.getNavChangeEmitter()
   .subscribe(data => {
     this.errMsg = data;
   });
  }
```

Can anybody help me? Thanks a lot

Comment: when and where is this `handleError`-function called?

Comment: @AJT_82 handleError is called in a base http service when anyone who need http services thanks

Comment: and it is extended by other services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly I resolved this by make a static Subject:

util.service.ts:

```
static errSubject: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject<any>('');
```

app.component.ts:

```
    UtilService.errSubject
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.errMsg = data;
      });
```

and do not forget provide UtilService in app.module.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Subject** as **Observable** as below.

```
import { Subject }    from 'rxjs/Subject';

export class UtilService {
  private message = = new Subject<string>();

  public errorMessage$ = this.message.asObservable();
  private error: string = '';

  private handleError(error: Response | any) {
    this.error = '';
    if (error instanceof Response) {
      const body = error.json() || '';
      const err = body['error'] || JSON.stringify(body);
      this.error = `${error['status']} - ${error['statusText'] || ''} ${err}`;
    } else {
      this.error = error['message'] ? error['message'] : error.toString();
    }
    console.error(this.error);
    this.message.next(this.error);
  }
}
```

// app.component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.utilService.errorMessage$.subscribe(error => {
    this.errMsg = error;
  });
}
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but I can not subscribe the Subject either